# Why my custom policy is not recognised in Sails JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, policies

Following this [screencast](http://irlnathan.github.io/sailscasts/blog/2013/08/28/building-a-sails-application-ep5-creating-a-policy-and-adding-client-side-validation/), I've created a policy in `api/policies/flash.js`. I then tried to use this policy in config/policies where at the beginning of the file I've used `'*':flash` so all my controllers would use this policy, however every time I tried to start Sails after this I got the error that `flash` is undefined. The code I've used in the aforementioned policy is this:

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {

res.locals.flash = {};

if(!req.session.flash) return next();

res.locals.flash = _.clone(req.session.flash);

// Clear flash
req.session.flash = {};

next();

};
```

I've also tried (like in the example in `config/policies.js`) `module.exports = function flash(req, res, next)...` and it also got the same error. In the screencast mentioned above the same steps did work perfectly. I've checked and rechecked to make it wasn't something I missed and couldn't find anything. I imagine it might be a version issue.

Can anyone clarify what I'm doing wrong?

Many thanks

Comment: Did you try `'*': 'flash'` (with apostrophes) in `config/policies.js`?

Comment: Nope, I've missed the apostrophes... hence it didn't work. Thanks for that. You want add as an answer so I can mark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything seems good except that in your `config/policies.js` it should be `'flash'` with apostrophes:

```
module.exports.policies = {
  '*': 'flash'
};
```