# Why is my custom policy not recognized in Sails JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I've been following this [screencast](http://youtu.be/_wL2cS0GmJQ?list=PLWsZeJCry-F4K4iRImeB3-i0S5mw9Ak-W), I've created a policy in `api/policies/flash.js`. I then tried making this policy usable to all of my controllers in `config/policies` using

```
module.exports.policies = {
  '*': 'flash'
};
```

However, when I try to access a view that requires the policy the console logs `flash is not defined` and my browser shows the view's path as an object.

Here is the code I'm using for the policy:

```
module.export = function(req, res, next) {

    res.locals.flash = {};

    if(!req.session.flash) return next();

    res.locals.flash = _.clone(req.session.flash);

    // clear flash
    req.session.flash = {};

    next();
};
```

It seems like there has been a very similar problem [posted on here before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21301449/why-my-custom-policy-is-not-recognised-in-sails-js), in that users case it was because he forgot the apostrophes around "flash" in the `config/policies.js` file.

Comment: Try logging to console ````res.locals.flash````` and ````req.session.flash```` in your policy using `````console.log(...)````. Also, could you post a short snippet of your controller code where you're flashing the message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your policy definition.  The code you pasted has "module.export" instead of "module.exports"